# When the Area will be minimum?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

**Background**

you have a yarn which has a length **L**. You have to make a shape which will occupy the **minimum area** that a shape can have.

**The Question**

Using calculus (differentiation of minimum and maximum of a function) it is easy to calculate the minimum area containing shape if the function of the area is known.

***But is it possible to denote a function for such shape?***

Comment: There is no minimum.  Can you imagine why?

Comment: @AndrewChin Probably its because a dot has zero area?

Comment: @AbuDozanaTahmid If the curve is simple then the result is interesting

Comment: Form a rectangle with width $w< \frac L2$, length $\frac L2 - w$. The area is $\left(\frac L2 - w\right)w$. Now consider what happens if you make $w$ smaller.

Comment: How is it easy using calculus “to calculate the minimum area containing shape”?

Comment: You should include that the shape must be able to cover the yarn, no matter what shape the yarn is given if you are allowed to move the shape around. I don't think it is easy at all.